# How to redirect to a page without removing a sidebar but the link in the address bar change

Tags: php, html

I make the question nice and clear.. you know the Facebook Real-Time Chat right? The `ChatList` or `ChatBox` that is in the right side of facebook where your online friends appear. When you navigate through accounts by pressing a link on facebook the menu bar and that chatbox is not removed or not included in the page refresh but the browser address bar change. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Framesets are the answer.

Comment: Facebook uses _framesets_? LOL I have no idea about facebook, would never use it, but that is still interesting. But even if, this does not explain the observed behavior.

Comment: You need to manage your HTML using JavaScript, do not reload the webpage directly, and use HTML5 History API to modify the webpage address.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Facebook using History API and a combination of AJAX and Backbone.js.

Also spine.js should do this.

Source: http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-change-page-content-and-URL-without-reloading-the-whole-page